# python code inconsistent indentation

Tags: python, sqlite, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have been working on a project which is getting the data from a temperature sensor that is connected to the arduino. I need to get that data to my raspberry pi and display it online. so I wrote python code that should get the data and put it in a sqlite database file. I try this code using python idle2 and idle 3 I cannot get it working. would be cause pf i have both python 2 and 3 installed to my rasbian? or there is a problem with the code?

here is the code;

```
#!/ussr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import serial
import datetime
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.open()

count = 0

con = lite.connect('data.db')

try:
  while 1:
    indata = ser.readline()
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    count = count + 1

    print indata + current_time
    print count

    with con:
      cur = con.cursor()
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES( ?, ?, ? )", (count, current_time, indata))

      if count > 100:
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM Temperatures")
        count = 0
Interrupt:
  ser.close()
```

Comment: `Interrupt:` should probably be something like `except Interrupt:`.

Comment: still not working.I even tried except KeyboardInterrupt:

Comment: "Not working" is not descriptive at all. What isn't working? What's the full error message?

Comment: the error is "invalid syntax"

Comment: i think it points at "print count"

Comment: You're using Python 3 then. Change `print foo` to `print(foo)` and it'll work.

Comment: yes it worked thank you!! but now i got the error saying that no module named serial.  which is "import serial" line4.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the 'Interrupt:' for 'except:'

Comment: nothing working. still gives me error at "print count" line23. The error is invalid syntax